# Eclipse RCP: Activating a view from an Editor without losing focus

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have a Tree Table in SWT.  I want to show a view when the user starts editing a field on the view.  However, I have the problem that when I go into the Editor, the activation of the view steals the focus of the editor, so I can't use it anymore.

What would be the correct way to activate a view from my Tree Cell Editor, without losing Focus?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "activate a view"? If I say "I activate a view" this is synonymous with "I give the view the focus"!?

Comment: You are right.  The view is already there.  I want to bring it to Focus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was using the method to showView() in the Active Page.

For this particular case, it is necessary to use the method bringToFront() instead of showView(), as bringToFront() does not steal the focus.

Comment: This solution only works if the specified view is already open. I did not find any way to open an editor for a specific input while keeping the focus on the currently selected part.

Comment: @parasietje I think what you need then is `showView(id, secondaryId, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_VISIBLE)`. Look at the documentation for the `mode` parameter: if `VIEW_VISIBLE` is supplied, then it is made visible but not given focus.

Comment: @JoseM.Benitez does this also work for an Editor in Eclipse 3.x ?

Comment: Oh cool, you have IWorkbenchPage#openEditor(input, editorId, activate). If activate is false, the editor is brought to the front without it receiving focus.

Comment: @parasietje Well done! I missed that you were looking for opening an editor. That's right, that's how yo do it. As far as I know, `showView` works only on `IViewPart`s.